# How To Pass Sensitive Data To JQuery

Tags: jquery

Using Django, I usually pass data to jquery functions like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");
    sensitive_data = $(this).attr('sensitive_data');
```

By doing it this way however, users can easily inspect the page and change values attached to the `div`s. This is not good as I want to pass several pieces of sensitive data (user id's etc) to my jquery functions.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sensitive data should never be handled on the client, it should be managed on the server.

Comment: Is the user id actually sensitive in this case?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. @GregBrodzik the button is for uploading a file. I'm passing the user id so I know which user to attach the file to in the DB. I'm worried that users will just change this field then attach doc's to other users.

Comment: I do not think a `user_id` can be sensitive unless its just only needed to open up a `money vault` or `personal documents`. You have to be specific when you say sensitive data.

Comment: @Brenden While the user_id is probably not in itself sensitive I think I understand your concern (any user could arbitrarily uploaded a file on behalf of another user). One way to address this is to track your users authenticated sessions with a signed token, embedding the user id. Pass that token on each user request via headers. Server-side, verify the token and and make sure the user_id matches the user_id on the file upload (this may moot the need explicitly pass user_id at all). Looks like you already have some token in the mix.

Comment: @GregBrodzik Okay, thank you. I'm using Django, so does this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signing/) look like what your talking about?